# How to print a output at each step of recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I already have the solution to the homework problem which is the following:

Write a function called funkyStuff(x) that does the following using RECURSION: Takes a number x digit by digit in reverse order , and returns the summation of each digit squared

Example: x = 1234

Output:

4 ** 2 = 16

3 ** 2 = 9

2 ** 2 = 4

1 ** 2 = 1

Sum of each squared digit: 30

I already have the recursive solution to the problem which is the code below, but the problem wants me to only use recursion to print the final answer.

```
def funkyStuff(x): 
    if x == 0: 
        return 0
    return ((x % 10)**2 + funkyStuff(int(x / 10))
```

Comment: Pro tip: `return` gets out of a function _immediately_, so the code after that `return` statement won't be executed

Comment: Sorry, I know,  I copied the wrong code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire point of recursion is to run until you hit your base case... so if you need to print out the final answer, put your print statement at your base case.

```
def funkyStuff(x): 
    if x == 0:
        print("Answer") 
        return 0
    return ((x % 10)**2 + funkyStuff(int(x / 10))
```

Comment: but I need to also print 4 **2, ... without a for loop